# Дан массив целых чисел. Удалить из него все элементы, кратные 3 или 5

Tags: c++, массивы

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    int i, c[] = { 9, 16, 20, 46, 29 };

    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        cout << c[i] << " ";
    }

    cout << endl;

    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        if ((c[i] % 5 != 0) || (c[i] % 3 != 0))
            cout << c[i] << " ";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>


int main()
{
    std::vector<int> input { 9, 16, 20, 46, 29 };

    for (const int i : input)
    {
        std::cout << i << " ";
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;

    const auto logical_end = std::remove_if(input.begin(), input.end(), [](const int i)
    {
        return !(i % 5) || !(i % 3);
    });

    input.erase(logical_end, input.end());

    for (const int i : input)
    {
        std::cout << i << " ";
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

[`std::remove_if`](https://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove) убирает из контейнера все числа, для которых верно условие `!(i % 5) || !(i % 3);`, то есть те, которые делятся без остатка на `3` или `5`.

В качестве первого аргумента передаём итератор начала вектора, в качестве второго - итератор конца вектора (то есть весь вектор).

В данном случае использован второй вариант функции, принимающий в качестве третьего аргумента предикат, задающий условие для удаления чисел из вектора. Используем [лямбда выражение](https://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda):

```
[](const int i) {return !(i % 5) || !(i % 3);}
```

При этом, `std::remove_if` не изменяет размер контейнера (не уменьшает его). Она возвращает итератор, указывающий на новый логический конец контейнера.

Поэтому после её вызова необходимо использовать какую-либо другую функцию, которая уменьшит размер контейнера до значения возвращённого `std::remove_if`.

Для этого мы используем метод вектора [`erase`](https://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase), где в качестве первого аргумента указываем новый логический конец вектора, а в качестве второго - текущий конец вектора.

Comment: Можно еще короче) строк так 10)

Comment: Можно. Но чтобы человек мог разобраться лучше расписать подробно. Это ведь не соревнование на самый короткий код.

Comment: ВЛ 80: Имхо, у вас ошибка в функции erase. Функция remove_if выполняется путём сдвига актуальных элементов внутри диапазона к началу. Возвращается итератор на новый конец диапазона. И удалить требуется элементы от нового конца диапазона до старого, т.е.: input.erase(logical_end, input.end() ). Иначе теряем элемент 16.

Comment: @anshap, Вы правы. Спасибо. Я торопился и был невнимателен.

Answer (score -1):

Вот еще 1 вариант решения)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>


int main() {

    std::vector<int> v{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
    std::copy(std::begin(v), std::end(v), std::ostream_iterator<int>{std::cout, " "});
    std::cout << std::endl;

    for (auto it{std::begin(v)}; it != std::end(v); it = std::next(it)) {
        if (*it % 3 == 0 || *it % 5 == 0) {
            v.erase(it--);
        }
    }

    std::copy(std::begin(v), std::end(v), std::ostream_iterator<int>{std::cout, " "});
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0; 
}
```